# Equations regarding exponential of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am having problems in proving the following equation:
Let $A=I-J$, where $I$ is an identity matrix, and $J$ is antisymmetric, and let $M$ be symmetric and positive definite. Then
$$A\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-As}Me^{-A^Ts}ds+\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-As}Me^{-A^Ts}ds\right)^T\right]=2M.$$
Could anyone help? Thanks for any comment!

Comment: @user619894 Sorry I made a mistake. I have edited the problem.

Comment: I think there still is a problem with the formula : when $M = I$, the formula outputs $A = I$. Is $J$ related to $M$ in some way ? Are you sure about the $A$ on the left ?

Comment: This and all previous edits of yours do not sound right. $X=\int_0^\infty e^{-sA}Me^{-sA^T}ds$ is the solution to the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) $AX+XA^T=M$.

Comment: @Theleb Thanks for the comment! Now I state the formula pretty much the same as in the paper.

Comment: @user1551 Now I edit the equation again. Do you see any clue? It seems to me that $X$ and $A^T$ does not commute in this case.

Comment: Your new edit still doesn't sound right. Note that $X$ is symmetric positive definite. So, you new edit is effectively suggesting that $2AX=2M$ or $AX=M$. However, since $AX+XA^T=M$, if $AX=M$, then $XA^T=0$ and hence $A=0$.

Comment: @user1551 you are right. Actually this formula arises from the paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10955-016-1491-2.pdf You can see the last line of page 475. Did I miss something?

Comment: It says for $C=\frac12X$, we have $x^TA(C+C^T)x=x^TMx$ (eq. 46a), **not** $A(C+C^T)=M$. In general, for any square matrix $B$, we have $x^TBx=(x^TBx)^T=x^TB^Tx$. Therefore $x^TBx=x^T\frac{B+B^T}{2}x$, i.e. $x^TBx$ is determined only by $x$ and the symmetric part of $B$. In your case, since $C$ is symmetric, $x^TA(C+C^T)x=2x^TACx=x^TAXx=x^T\frac{AX+X^TA^T}{2}x=x^T\frac{AX+XA^T}{2}x=x^TMx$.

Comment: Uh, wait, $x^T\frac{AX+XA^T}{2}x$ should be equal to $\frac12x^TMx$. I think the authors should remove the factor $1/2$ from the definition of $C$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130555/discussion-between-inbrevi-and-user1551).